# ¿Por qué aparece NaT y como hacer que aparezca la fecha?

Tags: python, pandas

Hola estoy convirtiendo una columna de un DataFrame que es de tipo string a fecha y cuando la convierto el valor que toma toda la columna es NaT, como puedo hacer que aparezca la fecha.
Gracias

Codigo:

```
import pandas as pd
movimientosCta = pd.read_csv('archivo.csv')      
movimientosCta['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(movimientosCta['Fecha'],errors = 'coerce')
```

antes  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] después
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Pues si hacer `to_datetime` te da NaT, es porque esos datos no se reconocen como fechas y el coerce atrapa la excepción y devuelve el equivalente de nan para datetime.

Si pruebas

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.to_datetime('jul-22', errors='coerce'))
```

Eso va a dar NaT por el coerce. Si le dejas que lo trate por defecto sin el errors, te tira la traza de error porque no sabe cómo transformar ese str. Tienes que usar el parámetro format que encuentras en [la documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Sí, hay que leer siempre la documentación oficial.

El format de acuerdo a la convencion usada en [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) sería:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.to_datetime('jul-21', format='%b-%y', errors='coerce'))
```

Esto daría el día 1 del año mes que estás dando, `2021-07-01 00:00:00`.